# Joining multiple tables + HAVING clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 4 tables :

```
create table Hotel (
numHotel int primary key,
nomHotel varchar(30),
ville varchar(30),
etoiles tinyint
);

create table Chambre (
numChambre int identity primary key,
numHotel int foreign key references Hotel(numHotel),
etage tinyint,
prixnuit smallmoney not null check (prixnuit>=100)
);

create table Client (
cinClient varchar(10) primary key,
nom varchar(30),
prenom varchar(30),
adresse varchar(255) default 'non renseignée',
telephone varchar(10) check (telephone like '0%' and len(telephone)=10)
);

create table reservation (
numReservation int identity primary key,
numChambre int foreign key references Chambre(numChambre),
numCl varchar(10) foreign key references Client(cinClient),
dateArrivee date,
dateDepart date,
constraint ck_dates check ((Datediff(day,dateArrivee,dateDepart)>0))
);
```

Column names are French, but I think they're understandable.

So the question is : I need to select the names of Hotels (nomHotel) having achieved a total price higher than a certain price (e.g. 10000)

This is what I did on paper :

```
select nomHotel from Hotel h join Chambre ch on h.numHotel=ch.numChambre join reservation r on ch.numChambre=r.numChambre
group by nomHotel
having COUNT(r.numChambre)*ch.prixnuit>10000
```

And (of course) I got it wrong.
Any Help is appreciated, Thanks.

translations : "prixnuit" is the room's (chambre) price per night.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The total revenue (I think) is based on the number of reservations.
I'm thinking you need to calculate the number of nights per reservation, no?
So, maybe:

```
select nomHotel,
    sum(Datediff(day,r.dateArrivee,r.dateDepart)*ch.prixnuit)
from Hotel h join Chambre ch on h.numHotel=ch.numChambre join reservation r       
on ch.numChambre=r.numChambre
group by nomHotel
having sum(Datediff(day,r.dateArrivee,r.dateDepart)*ch.prixnuit)>10000
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Done.­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 0):

```
select nomHotel, sum(Datediff(day,dateArrivee,dateDepart) * prixnuit)
from Hotel h join Chambre ch on h.numHotel=ch.numHotel 
           join reservation r on ch.numChambre=r.numChambre
group by nomHotel
having sum(Datediff(day,dateArrivee,dateDepart) * prixnuit)>1000
```